# Systemd service in package is restarted on upgrade

Tags: setuptools, systemd, restart, debhelper

I use debhelper with python setuptools in order to build my packages.
I recently updated the compatibility level 9 to 11 in order to use the systemd timers.

From that moment every time I upgrade the package the service contained is restarted.
I tried to build with the following rules:

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f

#export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export PYBUILD_NAME=my_pkg
export DH_ALWAYS_EXCLUDE=CVS:.svn:.git:.vscode*
export PYBUILD_INTERPRETERS=python3

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild

override_dh_installinit:
        dh_installinit --no-stop-on-upgrade --no-restart-on-upgrade --no-restart-after-upgrade --no-start

override_dh_systemd_enable:
        dh_systemd_enable --name=my_pkg

override_dh_systemd_start:
        dh_systemd_start --no-stop-on-upgrade --no-restart-on-upgrade --no-restart-after-upgrade --no-start
        python3 setup.py clean --all
```

According to the documentation those tags should do what I look for but probably there is something I'm missing:

[dh_systemd_start](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_systemd_start.1.en.html)

[dh_installinit](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installinit.1.en.html)

Every time I update it the service contained is restarted.
The service is running the update itself so when is restarted the update is left uncompleted.

Answer (score 0):

As expected I was looking in the wrong direction.
The correct option to use is:
[dh_installsystemd](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installsystemd.1.en.html)

change the **rule** file into:

```
#! /usr/bin/make -f

#export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export PYBUILD_NAME=my_pkg
export DH_ALWAYS_EXCLUDE=CVS:.svn:.git:.vscode*
export PYBUILD_INTERPRETERS=python3

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild

override_dh_systemd_enable:
        dh_systemd_enable --name=my_pkg

override_dh_installsystemd:
        dh_installsystemd --no-restart-after-upgrade

override_dh_systemd_start:
        python3 setup.py clean --all
```

I hope this will help someone else in the same situation.